# crosstool-ng build fails on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: cross-compilation

I am trying to follow this tutorial

http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/

There are no known issues that relate to this 404 not found error

Fails on step 15 -> Run ct-ng build.

I get this error, I even tried different versions (The same as the tutorial and the latest)

```
[ALL  ]    --2012-10-28 21:16:04--  
http://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro/4.7/4.7-  2012.07/+download/gcc-linaro-4.7-2012.07
[ALL  ]    Resolving launchpad.net (launchpad.net)... 91.189.89.223, 91.189.89.222
[ALL  ]    Connecting to launchpad.net (launchpad.net)|91.189.89.223|:80... connected.
[ALL  ]    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
[ALL  ]    2012-10-28 21:16:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.
[ALL  ]    
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components'    tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: do_cc_get[scripts/build/cc/gcc.sh@592]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@538]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/opt/cross/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.16.0/B - Known issues.txt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like launchpad.net changed their download URL, the correct URL is:

`https://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro/4.7/4.7-2012.07/+download/gcc-linaro-4.7-2012.07.tar.bz2`

You should edit `/usr/local/ct-ng.1.16.0/scripts/build/cc/gcc.sh` on lines 26 to read:
`CT_GetFile "" \`

and on line 30 to read:
`"${linaro_base_url}/${linaro_series}/${linaro_version}/+download/gcc-linaro-${linaro_version}.tar.bz2"`

This is a quick hack and should be reported to the devs of crosstool-ng for a proper fix.

Comment: Thanks, still waiting for the build but the url is correct now

Comment: Still errors, I wont waste any more time on this :(

Comment: Pastebin them man, I have the time to help. If you edited as I said above all should work.

Comment: The error -> 'gcc-linaro-4.7-2012.07' not found in'/media/space/home/peter/src/raspberrypi/stagedir/.bu  ild/tarballs' I have used binaries from CodeSourcery succesfully - thanks for your help though @Jake

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Instead of changing the script and hoping for the best I just ran `ct-ng menuconfig` again, chose a different non-linaro compiler and tried running `ct-ng build`. Then all tools were downloaded successfully. Now I am waiting for the build to finish.

EDIT: Build successful and the result compiles my C code for ARM. Haven't tested on Pi yet.

Comment: The simple stuff worked for me on Pi but as soon as I tried to include libraries (like opencv) it failed

Comment: So far I have only used the standard library and BCM2835 library to use the GPIOs. It works, but I had some issues getting the library built for the correct architecture.